# How to pass a value from one function to another in event handler methods in c#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, c#-5.0

I have list box populated using web-client and I used , for-loop to separate object from json response for my use ,I need to use those objects throughout the class ,i.e I need to use those values in all the methods,It will be even feasible if can Pass from one method to another

Code:

```
void Downloadpage()
{
    WebClient webclient = new WebClient();

    webclient.Headers["ContentType"] = "application/json";
    webclient.DownloadStringCompleted += wc_downloadStringCompleted;
    webclient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://client.web.net/pages_wp.php"), UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);          
}

public void wc_downloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    string lreport = e.Result.ToString();
    string lnoHTMLs = Regex.Replace(lreport, @"<[^>]+>|&nbsp;|&zwnj;|&raquo;|&laquo;|&ldquo;|\\n|\\t|", "", RegexOptions.Multiline).Trim();
    string lnoHTMLNormaliseds = Regex.Replace(lnoHTMLs, @"\s{2,}", " ");


    JArray res = JArray.Parse(lnoHTMLNormaliseds);
news = new List<jsons>();


            string rId = res[0]["raportId"].ToString();            ---->a
            string rTitle = res[0]["raportTitle"].ToString();      --->b
            news.Add(new jsons() { raportId = rId, raportTitle = rTitle});


        Presslist.ItemsSource = news;
}
```

I need to access values in 'a'and 'b' in another button click event as below

```
private void Add_to_cart(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //values need to come here
}
```

**Note:** Add_to_cart is triggered on button click

Comment: Use class level variables.

Comment: Didn't get you, you have several `rId` and `rTitle`. You want all of them to be stored and accessed in other methods?

Comment: You have multiple `rId` and `rTitle`. Which ones do you need to access at button click event

Comment: I have only on rId and rTitle and yes I need them to accesed

Comment: this one  news.Add(new jsons() { raportId = rId, raportTitle = rTitle });

Comment: You are enumerating a `JArray` using `foreach` and assigning each `rId` and `rTitle` to a  `List<json>`. There is obviously more than one `rId` and `rTitle`

Comment: only the first value from loop

Comment: What are the types stored in the `JArray`, are they `JObjects`?

Answer (score 1):

Make the variables class level

```
String _rId ="";
String _rTitle ="";

void Downloadpage()
{
    WebClient webclient = new WebClient();

    webclient.Headers["ContentType"] = "application/json";
    webclient.DownloadStringCompleted += wc_downloadStringCompleted;
    webclient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://client.web.net/pages_wp.php"),
UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);          
}

public void wc_downloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    string lreport = e.Result.ToString();
    string lnoHTMLs = Regex.Replace(lreport, @"<[^>]+>|&nbsp;|&zwnj;|&raquo;|&laquo;|&ldquo;|\\n|\\t|", "", RegexOptions.Multiline).Trim();
    string lnoHTMLNormaliseds = Regex.Replace(lnoHTMLs, @"\s{2,}", " ");


    JArray res = JArray.Parse(lnoHTMLNormaliseds);
news = new List<jsons>();


            string rId = res[0]["raportId"].ToString();           // ---->a
            string rTitle = res[0]["raportTitle"].ToString();     // --->b
            news.Add(new jsons() { raportId = rId, raportTitle = rTitle});
            _rId = rId;
            _rTitle = rTitle;


        Presslist.ItemsSource = news;
}

private void Add_to_cart(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //values need to come here
   //_rId
   //_rTitle
}
```

Comment: Without making it class level ,any options to pass between methods

Comment: I do not see how you could do it without class level variables. Since you want access to them from within the event 'Add_to_cart' they need to exist somewhere that can be accessed from within the scope of that function.

Answer (score 1):

I think the place where you are calling your `Downloadpage()` method can save these values in a common place. May be `Session Level` or `Application level` space.

I think that `Add_to_cart()` method is a button click event so the DownloadPage should be called in page load event  or any *event prior to display the UI*. 
And when the `Add_to_cart()` is called than you can retrieve the values and use them.